# Smoke the SmokeDetector

Tags: script, chat

## SmokeTheSmokeDetector

Over in [Tavern on the Meta](http://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/89/tavern-on-the-meta), our spam detector, SmokeDetector has been the topic of an ongoing argument between those who believe SmokeDetector fills the chatroom, and those who believe his service is payment enough.

While you can ignore users, you can't *exactly* ignore specific replies to Smokey without ignoring users, so I wrote this:

A UserScript to hide SmokeDetector messages and replies/calls to it by other users.

Here's a before and after shot:

[image]

It doesn't hide `blame` or `amiprivileged` messages.

This code is also available to review on [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/123082/smoke-the-smokedetector).

---

## Install

[Click Here](https://github.com/The-Quill/SmokeTheSmokeDetector/raw/master/SmokeTheSmokeDetector.user.js) to install. It's also available on [GitHub](https://github.com/The-Quill/SmokeTheSmokeDetector) under the MIT license.